# TikZ Mindmaps: Set angle between node vertices, instead of centers

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

In

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\tikzset{
    every node/.append style={concept, minimum size=0cm, inner sep=2mm, text width=, minimum size=0cm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,text=white,fill=white]
\path node {O} [clockwise from=45, level 1/.append style={sibling angle=60} ]
child { node[align=center] {AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA} }
child { node[align=center] {AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA} }
child { node {BBB} }
child { node {BBB} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

one can see that the white space between the two big A nodes is smaller than that between the two B nodes.

[image: illustration]

How do I set the angle between node vertices, instead of node centers (here set with `sibling space`), so that the white space is always the same?

Comment: I have the feeling that this question is kind of covered by your other one. I mean technically you were asking about node distance there, and node angles here, but the two issues are related and solving one, might solve the other in the process.

Comment: @Alenanno: Well, we are supposed to ask questions separately. Also, I don't see how they are related.

Comment: Your title is misleading... As far as I know there is no easy way.

Comment: @Symbol1 You mean: because nodes do not have edges at all? And, if we read 'edge' as 'border', then rectangular nodes have a border consisting of four sides, so it isn't clear what the angle is supposed to be between? The angle is already, I guess, set between the edges drawn *to* the nodes within the tree. (I'm not sure how the angle could be between the nodes' centres, either. It must be between paths or edges or something of that kind rather than between points.)

Comment: @Make42 As I said about your other question, I don't think you should be trying to use `mindmap` at all. `mindmap` is a particular style of tree diagram. You can tweak the style a bit but, in the end, if you want a completely different style of diagram, it just doesn't make sense to use `mindmap` since you must first undo its configuration and then do your own, whereas otherwise only the latter is required. Though I doubt that there is going to be an easy way of ensuring equal amounts of white space between the borders of rectangular nodes arranged cyclically around a central root.

Comment: @cfr I thought `edge` is something that connects vertices(=nodes). Despite the term, OP is clearly asking how to arrange nodes "freely", which is, to my limited knowledge, pretty difficult.

Comment: @Symbol1 I thought `edge` was just a special kind of `path`. (I guess I'd think of vertices as points which might belong to nodes or be coordinates.) But you know more about this than I do by a long way. But I also think what is being asked is not easy. I especially think that `mindmap` is not going to help since it more-or-less imposes a style which is diametrically opposed to the one the OP wants....

Comment: @Symbol1: I get that the word "edge" has multiple meanings so I substituted it with "vertex". (English isn't my mother's tongue.)

Answer (score 1):

I have only sad news.

`mindmap` uses Ti*k*Z's `child` syntax. So let's take a look at how Ti*k*Z deals with `child`.

> ```
> \def\tikz@childnode[#1]#2{%
>   \advance\tikznumberofcurrentchild by1\relax%
>   {\tikzset{every child/.try,#1}\expandafter}%
>   \iftikz@child@missing%
>     \tikzgdeventcallback{node}{}%
>   \else%
>   \setbox\tikz@whichbox=\hbox\bgroup%
>     \unhbox\tikz@whichbox%
>     \hbox\bgroup\bgroup%
>         \pgfinterruptpath%
>           \pgfscope%
>             \let\tikz@transform=\pgfutil@empty%
>             \tikzset{every child/.try,#1}%
>             \tikz@options%
>             \tikz@transform%            
>             \let\tikz@transform=\relax%
>             \tikz@grow%
>             % Typeset node:
>             \edef\tikz@parent@node@name{[name=\tikzparentnode-\the\tikznumberofcurrentchild,style=every child node]}%
>             \def\tikz@child@node@text{[shape=coordinate]{}}
>             \tikz@parse@child@node#2\pgf@stop%
>             \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\node
>             \expandafter\tikz@parent@node@name
>               \tikz@child@node@text
>               \pgfextra{\global\let\tikz@childnode@name=\tikz@last@fig@name};%
>             \let\tikzchildnode=\tikz@childnode@name%
>             {%
>               \def\tikz@edge@to@parent@needed{edge from parent}
>               \ifx\tikz@child@node@rest\pgfutil@empty%
>                 \path edge from parent;%
>               \else%
>                 \path \tikz@child@node@rest \tikz@edge@to@parent@needed;%
>               \fi%
>             }%
>         \endpgfscope%
>       \endpgfinterruptpath%
>     \egroup\egroup%
>   \egroup%
>   \fi%
> }
> ```

It is long. But the logic is clear:

- `\tikz@grow` grows the tree. That is, it moves the "pen" to the expected position of a child (or grandchild, or grandgra... you know...)
- `\node` typesets a node, whose size is not known yet.

So we find that there is no trivial way to move a child (or grandchild, or...) based on its size. Perhaps you can do something after `\node`, but then you need to take care of the next node because the next call of `\tikz@grow` does not know what is going on. We then start to consider canceling `\tikz@grow` once and for all. After all, as @cfr has concluded ahead:

> you must first undo its configuration and then do your own, whereas  otherwise only the latter is required.

So the last question is: what else we can do? will, in the manual, page 429 there is a picture

[image]

which should be a good start.